# Sum up number in loop

Tags: c#, .net, listbox

I want to add the total for lots of amounts in a Listbox, but I couldn't able to do it, How to do it.

I tried to get the total of lots of amounts but I failed.

```
double totalamount = 0;
for (int i = 0; i <= lstProductQuantity.Items.Count - 2; i++)
{
    totalamount = double.Parse(textBox2.Text);
}

textBox2.Text = totalamount.ToString();
```

I think so this is the wrong way I am doing it, please help me.

Actually, it should get the total amount of all amounts, but nothing is happening using this code.

Comment: You need `totalamount += double.Parse(textBox2.Text);`.

Comment: "I need to add.." then you should add using `+`

Comment: what is `totalamount` meant to represent? the sum of all Items in `lstProductQuantity` ? or simply the total amount of all items?

Comment: Looks like you are not counting the last value `lstProductQuantity.Items.Count - 2` should be `-1` and you are adding the value in the textbox each time `double.Parse(textBox2.Text);`, not the value of the item you are trying to add, should be something like `double.Parse(lstProductQuantity[i].` and its property

Comment: what is `lstProductQuantity`? which type? is it a listbox? combobox? something else? How does 1 `Item` look like? probably a string representation?=! does it have multiple columns? is it only 1 number? does it contain spaces? If you can answer all my questions, we will be much more capable to answer your question.

Comment: i am just making a inventory system for my company so for while i go on adding many projects to listbox after all added i want get the total for all small amounts

Comment: please post the code where you insert the data into you listbox

Answer (score 1):

try [untested]:

```
double totalamount = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < lstProductQuantity.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            double itemAmount = 0;
            if(double.TryParse(lstProductQuantity.Items[i], out itemAmount))
            {
               totalamount += itemAmount;
            }
        }
        textBox2.Text = totalamount.ToString();
```

Although this might work, you should do your calculation using the same data that you use to populate the list box. ie prepare your data, then present this to the visual controls.

Comment: error on this line                                                                                                      linetotalamount += double.Parse(lstProductQuantity.Items[i]);

Comment: @TharminiAnandasivanesan "error on this line" mate, please be a little more specific. We neither can read your screen nor your mind! what does the error say?

Comment: @TharminiAnandasivanesan: The intention of my answer is for you to read it and get the gist of what I am saying, I have indicated that it is "untested". Your original code needs to loop through ALL the items and you need to convert/cast each item value and add that to your total value. This is the info you need to get your code working.

Comment: do you have any other media sir because i can't send any images i can only explain through images only can you help me sir

Comment: @TharminiAnandasivanesan you can upload images into your question

Comment: @TharminiAnandasivanesan [how to upload image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/344851/how-do-you-add-a-screenshot-image-to-your-stack-overflow-post)

Comment: @MarkRedman `Items` is a collection of `object`s and `Parse` doesn't like it. Try adding a `lstProductQuantity.Items[i].ToString()`

Comment: @MongZhu: Sure, lets say this is pseudocode that needs to be interpreted... I only have limited time for this answer...

Comment: @MongZhu: And you point supports my suggestion of doing this using the data, not the values inthe list.

Comment: @MarkRedman   if(double.TryParse(lstProductQuantity.Items[i], out itemAmount))   this line is showing error here i am using listbox sir

Comment: @TharminiAnandasivanesan: ok, are you waiting for the solution, I would suggest, trying to debug this and see what the value lstProductQuantity.Items[i] is, i s it null is it a value that will parse? This should give you a clue into what the error may be.. maybe put a try catch around it to catch it and see, but you have all the info you need to try and work out where the issues it.

Comment: @MarkRedman error is cannot convert object to string how can sort it out

Comment: @TharminiAnandasivanesan: The list gets populated by data of some sort, instead of reading the list and doing the calculation, do the calculation on the same data, so you can loop through the objects and use the relevant property.

Answer (score 0):

This is your problem.

```
totalamount = double.Parse(textBox2.Text);
```

Change this to

```
totalamount += double.Parse(textBox2.Text);
```

It looks like that you are getting only the last entry, because you are always rewriting totalamount variable. 
This is equivalent of doing

```
totalamount = totalamount + double.Parse(textBox2.Text);
```

As pointed out by Mong Zhu, when parsing, you should always check for exception. What happens if text is not number? Probably exception will occur. Always wrap this in try catch block.

By the way, I also noticed weird condition in for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= lstProductQuantity.Items.Count - 2; i++)
```

Why -2? Why are you not including last item? I think this should be like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lstProductQuantity.Items.Count; i++)
```

or

```
for (int i = 0; i <= lstProductQuantity.Items.Count -1 ; i++)
```

This is working for me:

```
double totalamount = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < lstProductQuantity.Items.Count; i++) {
    totalamount += lstProductQuantity[i];
}
textBox2.Text = totalamount.ToString();
```

Also, Mark Redman gave you great solution with try parse. Combine both and you have pretty decent solution

Comment: No answer is coming from where? Console.WriteLine(totalamount) should show correct value. What is debugger saying?

Comment: @TharminiAnandasivanesan might it be that you get an exception because you cannot parse the value in `textBox2.Text` ?

Comment: @MongZhu ofcourse. Added to my answer. Thank you for pointing that out

Comment: nothing is showing, if tried nothing coming no changes in the program

Comment: Please provide what have you tried (provide minimum viable example)

Comment: @TharminiAnandasivanesan ... is textBox2.Text empty? I hope that you know what this code will do? Basically it will do `double.Parse(textBox2.Text) * lstProductQuantity.Items.Count`

Comment: `double.Parse(lstProductQuantity[i]);` doesn't compile. you would need a string

Comment: @MongZhu ofcourse, I copy/paste gone wrong. We do not need to cast anything if items are of proper type. If not. ToString() method to the rescue :)

Comment: I meant that `Parse` only accepts strings!. Since the `lstProductQuantity` is a `ListBox` the items are of type `object` you also cannot simply add them using `+=`

Comment: Yes, but you can still cast them from object to whatever type you need (integer, double, float,...)